# Поиск по ListView динамически?

Tags: android

Всем привет. Интересует следующий вопрос.
Я сделал кнопку поиск в action bar

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>
```

Выглядит это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот, ниже у меня будет список (ListView), и я хотел узнать, как при каждом нажатии на букву список фильтровался под введенное значение?

Я делал это через обычные editText.
У него есть событие TextChangeListener

```
     private class TextChangeListener implements TextWatcher {

/////
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());


            }

/////

        }
```

А вот на какое событие вешать поиск в ActionBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кратко, то для реализации конкретно вашей задачи код будет примерно такой:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
  ...
  MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
  SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText){
  adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query){

}
```

То есть получаете виджет поиска, получаете для него actionView (то, что отображается при тапе на лупу), вешаете на него соответствующий обработчик.

---

Если делать правильно (например, если захотите корректную обработку хардварной кнопки поиска на старых девайсах), то делать надо через создание поисковой Activity, для которой необходимо сформировать настройки поиска, прописать в манифесте фильтр интента для поиска, при создании меню заполнять настройки поиска SearchViewInfo в виджет поиска (SearchView) через SearchManager, далее при поиске обрабатывать получение нового интента (onNewIntent), фильтровать адаптер.

С данным механизмом лучше ознакомиться в [документации](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html).

Comment: Отличный ответ спасибо. А класс нужно наследовать от какого нибудь интерфейса?

Comment: @duddeniska, да SearchView.OnQueryTextListener. В любой ide среда будет подчеркивать и давать возможность прописать все наследования, вручную писать ничего не придется... В Android Studio, например, alt-enter на подчеркнутом `searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);` и дальше оно само все подскажет и добавит...

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас начну делать, но ответ я думаю правильный, Принимаем)

Answer (score 0):

Если смотреть по документации то скорей всего этот метод

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle presses on the action bar items
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        openSearch();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_compose:
        composeMessage();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```